# Halmos: Not catching my obvious bug

Tags: foundry, halmos

I have the following smart contract that I'm looking to apply formal verification to.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

contract FuzzCanCatch {
    uint256 public total;

    constructor() {
        total = 100;
    }

    // Invariant: this should never revert
    function hellFunc(uint128 randomNumber) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 response = total / randomNumber;
        return response;
    }
}
```

The above function has an invariant that `hellFunc` should never return 0, however, it obviously returns 0 when 0 is passed as input.

The following test case attempts to apply FV to it. Fuzzing easily solves it.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {StdInvariant} from "forge-std/StdInvariant.sol";
import {FuzzCanCatch} from "../../src/invariant-break/fuzz-cant-catch/FuzzCanCatch.sol";

contract FuzzCantCatchTest is StdInvariant, Test {
    FuzzCanCatch fuzzCanCatch;

    function setUp() public {
        fuzzCanCatch = new FuzzCanCatch();
    }

    function testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz(uint128 randomNumber) public view {
        uint256 response = fuzzCanCatch.hellFunc(randomNumber);
        assert(response >= 0);
    }
}
```

```
$ forge test --mt testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz
[⠰] Compiling...
[⠒] Compiling 56 files with 0.8.20
[⠢] Solc 0.8.20 finished in 11.37s
Compiler run successful!

Running 1 test for test/invariant/FuzzCantCatchTest.t.sol:FuzzCantCatchTest
[FAIL. Reason: Division or modulo by 0 Counterexample: calldata=0x0xb7cfac490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, args=[0]] testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz(uint128) (runs: 47, μ: 7791, ~: 7791)
Test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 2.83ms
```

But `halmos` does not.

```
 $ halmos --function testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz
[⠰] Compiling...
[⠒] Compiling 56 files with 0.8.20
[⠢] Solc 0.8.20 finished in 11.39s
Compiler run successful!

Running 1 tests for test/invariant/FuzzCantCatchTest.t.sol:FuzzCantCatchTest
[PASS] testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz(uint128) (paths: 1/3, time: 0.04s, bounds: [])
Symbolic test result: 1 passed; 0 failed; time: 0.07s
```

(Passing is a bad thing)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halmos ignores normal reverts and only catches assertion failures -- so we need to assert that the function did not revert.

To fix, you can do a low level call and check the return value on the test instead.

```js
function testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz(uint128 number) public view {
        // uint256 response = fuzzCanCatch.hellFunc(randomNumber);
        // assert(response >= 0);
        // perform low level call
        (bool success,) =
            address(fuzzCanCatch).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(fuzzCanCatch.hellFunc.selector, number));
        assert(success);
    }
```

And get the following output:

```
halmos --function testCatchEasyBugWithFuzz
```